# Bugs with ETL project Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, excel-2010, etl

Trying to create an integration services project where I use an "OLE DB source" object in which I execute an SQL query that extracts 120,000 rows and 120 columns. I want to dump that data set into a ".xlsx" file. However, Visual Studio 2017 neither finds nor recognizes the worksheet.

I am trying to generate a ".xlsx" file from an SQL query from Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I am using Visual Studio 2017, I installed the Business Intelligence packages, and through an Integration Services project, I want to fetch the data from Microsoft SQL Server and place it inside my ".xlsx" file. However, the IDE only lets me work with ".xls" files.

Ruled Out Issues:

- Read and write permissions; I am using the computer as an administrator and run each software as such...
- Incompatible drivers; I checked for Visual, Excel, OS, and the project execution is being done in 64 bits.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Excel Destination Adapter to generate MS Excel files.

VS2017 is a 32-bit application. That's why you need to install Microsoft ACE OLEDB Provider 32-bit on your developer workstation. Version 12.0, 15.0, or 16.0. Just one of them.

Also, you would need to switch SSIS Project in VS2017 to 32-bit mode too via

```
Run64BitRuntime=False
```

SSIS run-time environment on a server would need Microsoft ACE OLEDB Provider 64-bit. It doesn't have VS2017 limitations.